# How to verify if the user is agent or administrator yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have made my table for users : PK - ID, username, password, status, role
For roles i have declared in my model const ROLE_ADMIN = 1, const ROLE_VISITOR = 2;

I want to allow the login if the user is admin, or to reject the login if the user is visitor. I will have all the users imported, but the application will be accessed only by few of them, so i want to deny the login for any other tipe of user.

For this

```
[
  'allow' => true,
  'roles' => ['@'],
],
```

Where should i declare a function to use instead of `'allow' => true,` `'allow'=>function` and verify if `$this->role == 1`

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE FOR ANY SUGGESTIONS.

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * UsersController implements the CRUD actions for User model.
 */
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],      
        ];
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all User models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new UserSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single User model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new User model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing User model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing User model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the User model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return User the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property int $status
 * @property int $role
 *
 * @property Equipment[] $equipments
 * @property UserEquipmentMapping[] $userEquipmentMappings
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    const STATUS_AVAILABLE = 1;
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 2;

    const ROLE_ADMIN = 1;
    const ROLE_VISITOR = 2;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password', 'status', 'role'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'role'], 'integer'],
            [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'role' => 'Role',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Equipments]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|EquipmentQuery
     */
    public function getEquipments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Equipment::className(), ['user_for_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[UserEquipmentMappings]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|UserEquipmentMappingQuery
     */
    public function getUserEquipmentMappings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserEquipmentMapping::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return UserQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new UserQuery(get_called_class());
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        #$u  =  static::findOne($username);#
        #print_r($username);die;
    
        $u = User::find()
            ->where(['username' => $username])
            ->one();
        
        return $u;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        #$u = User::find()
        #   ->where(['username' => $username])
        #   ->one();
        
        return $this->username;
        #return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['username' => 'username_id']);
    }

        public function getAuthKey()
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRole(){
        return $this->role;
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
     
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
       
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {

        return $this->password === $password;
    }
    
/*  public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('last_name','first_name','age','username','password', 'safe'),
        );
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL above. Do you want an SQL answer?)

Comment: sorry for <sql> tag, i thought it could provide help. i removed it

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to allow one set of actions for "normal" Users and one for Administrators, then it might be worth checking out the Advanced template, which would allow you to allocate permissions separately in the frontend and backend.  However, if I understand your comment in reply to the first version of this answer, then what you are actually intending is to import a complete set of Users from another context (Active Directory) and then give some of them Admin access to your Yii2 application.

You say you want to allow the login if the user is admin, or to reject the login if the user is visitor, which is still a bit ambiguous.  Do you not in fact mean that the non-admins are simply Guests (the term Yii uses)?

If the visitors cannot log in, then they cannot be differentiated from one another, and you don't need to - in fact I would suggest that you probably should not - keep them in the same table as your admins.  You would probably be better off simply allocating logins to your admins, and controlling those with the code you've posted above: 1) a controller for actions and 2) your identity interface, plus /models/LoginForm.php.

You would then create a separate table for the Active Directory users, complete with its own model, views and controller, within which you would give your Admins permission to perform CRUD functions on those records.

You need an action in one of your controllers to display the login form, and there is a ready-rolled one in the basic template, whose model is models/LoginForm.php, and *that* is where you can most easily write/alter code to log admins in (and potentially ignore "normal" users / visitors).  If you separate the tables though, it will work out of the box - because only your admins will be in the table it references.

*Then* you can use behaviors in controllers to allow or deny access to different levels of user (roles).  There is a good tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-user-access-controls--cms-23173).  Note that the syntax for behaviors for Guests is a question mark (as opposed to the @ symbol for authenticated users).  A good tip here is not to mix publicly-visible and admin-only actions in the same controller, because it simplifies the necessary behaviors code.

The last thing I would suggest is that, if you are going to use a permissions hierarchy, you should rearrange your user permission levels (constants) in the opposite order to the one you've used - the higher the value, the greater the permissions.  I tend to use a 7-level system (actually 6 + 1, where 0 is no permissions whatsoever and 6 is Super-User), but in combination with a set of systems, so that users have permissions per system.  This has been sufficient for every system I've built or worked on, but sounds excessive for your needs.

In summary, it sounds like you can achieve what you want with Admins in the table used by IdentityInterface, Active Directory users in a different table, and a simple Guest / Authenticated User delineation.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. My intention is to have the users imported from Active Directory, but only a few people will have acces to application. So on i want to allow login only to a small part of the entire user list. I want to allow access only to the ones that have ROLE_ADMIN, having a column in my user database with role. I want this because i need all the users for the scope of the application.

Comment: @Liviu, I shall edit my answer in the light of your comment.